# To cancel pending HTTP request & trigger fromEvent again in Angular 6 & Rxjs 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm able to cancel the pending HTTP request (using .unsubscribe), but after this it won't trigger my fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup'). How do I handle it?

I'm using "fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')" to fetch search results. But if there is a pending HTTP request and the user clears the field, I want to cancel the request (i tried unsubscribe & it works). But, after that the 'fromEvent' won't trigger. Any idea how to handle it?

```
fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .pipe(
                map((event: any) => {
                    if (event.keyCode === 17 || event.keyCode === 91 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 27) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return event.target.value;
                }),
                filter((query: any) => {
                    if (query === '') {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.searchedResult = [];
                    }
                    return query && query.length > 0;
                }),
                debounceTime(300)
                ,distinctUntilChanged((p, c) => {
                    return !!this.searchedResult && this.searchedResult.length > 0 && (p == c);
                })
                , switchMap(query => {
                    query = query.trim();
                    this.loading = true;
                    return this.cartService.searchItemByName(encodeURIComponent(query), this.shopID.shop_id.toString()).pipe(
                        catchError(err => {
                            this.toaster.error(err.error.message || "Something went wrong!");
                            return of([]); //in case of error let’s emit an empty array
                        })
                    );
                })
            ).subscribe((res: any) => {
            let data = res.result;
            this.loading = false;
            this.searchedResult = data;
            if (data && data.length) this.setSelectedItem(data[0], 0)
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwitchMap already cancels the subscription if a new search term comes across. So I'd remove the side effects from your code and handle the empty term case not with a filter but with a conditional return.

```
fromEvent(document.getElementById('source'), 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        map((event: any) => event.target.value),
        debounceTime(300),
        switchMap(query => {
            const trimmed = query.trim();
            this.loading = true;
            return trimmed === '' ? of([]) : fakeHttp(query);
        })
    )
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(res);
    });
```

In action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tg4gew?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Ah! got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

takeUntil could do the job here:

```js
searchInputEvent = new Subject();

fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.searchInputEvent.next()),
                map((event: any) => {
                    if (event.keyCode === 17 || event.keyCode === 91 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 27) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return event.target.value;
                }),
                filter((query: any) => {
                    if (query === '') {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.searchedResult = [];
                    }
                    return query && query.length > 0;
                }),
                debounceTime(300)
                ,distinctUntilChanged((p, c) => {
                    return !!this.searchedResult && this.searchedResult.length > 0 && (p == c);
                })
                , switchMap(query => {
                    query = query.trim();
                    this.loading = true;
                    return this.cartService.searchItemByName(encodeURIComponent(query), this.shopID.shop_id.toString()).pipe(
                        takeUntil(this.searchInputEvent),
                        catchError(err => {
                            this.toaster.error(err.error.message || "Something went wrong!");
                            return of([]); //in case of error let’s emit an empty array
                        })
                    );
                })
            ).subscribe((res: any) => {
            let data = res.result;
            this.loading = false;
            this.searchedResult = data;
            if (data && data.length) this.setSelectedItem(data[0], 0)
        })
```

It's gonna unsubscribe from previously subscribed **searchItemByName** observable each type the keyup event is triggered. You can consider that the request should be cancelled as soon as the user types in, or only when the debounce time is over. In that case, place the **tap** after the debounceTime